# Oracle - REGEXP_SUBSTR leading zeroes ignored issue

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

While execution below query I'm getting "235" instead of expected results "0"

```
select  REGEXP_SUBSTR(000.235||'', '[^.]+', 1, 1)  from dual;
```

Comment: Can you explain, please, what you want to achieve by regexp?

Answer (score 5):

Do this instead, and you'll see where the problem comes:

```
select  000.235||'' from dual
```

Result:

```
.235
```

The regexp picks up the first longest occurrence of non-period, which in this string is "235", so it's working correctly; it's the input value that is broken

Now, if you'd written it like this, it would be fine:

```
select  REGEXP_SUBSTR('000.235', '[^.]+', 1, 1)  from dual
```

So why the odd presentation of the numeric? What does your data in your table look like? This is unlikely to be the actual query you're running - if you need help with the true query, post it up

Comment: HI @Caius, Thanks for the response. i was under assumption that oracle type cast to string without any manipulation with using by appending the character. my primary task was to pick numeric value upto 2 decimal without any round of in sql. Thanks again :-D

Comment: Hi ajit, it probably does cast to string without manipulating, it's just that 000.325 will be represented as a number in form .235 automatically - there isn't any way in any computer system I know of to keep three leading zeroes in a number .. only as a numerical string :)

Answer (score 3):

Oracle trim numeric values, you can fix it by adding ltrim to number:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(ltrim(' 000.235')||'', '[^.]+', 1, 1) from dual;
```

result: `000` as expected